# List All Open Project On Android Studio

Tags: android, shortcut

Is there any shortcuts to see my list of open projects in android studio? Currently what I do is that sliding one window to see the other project.

Comment: Change the tab on the left side from Android to Projects?

Comment: you can just click right button of mouse to Android Studio icon(on Mac)

Comment: as mentioned above, you can use the App icon to view that.
Or use `cmd+\`` on Mac to cycle through the open windows of that Application.
You can also go to `Help -> Default Key Reference` to explore the shortcuts available.

Answer (score 1):

In the IDE, open the Window menu.